# Zshell completion calling another function

Tags: zsh, prezto

I'm written several zsh functions for tmux. I'm trying to add autocompletion to a few of these functions, but I'm running into trouble.

One of these functions is `tk`, a shorthand for `tmux kill-session`. This function takes the name of a session to kill and falls back to the current session if one isn't provided.

Here's what my function looks like:

```
function tk {
  if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
    tmux kill-session -t $1
  else
    tmux kill-session
  fi
}
```

I've also written an `active_tmux_sessions` function that's used in a few other places:

```
function active_tmux_sessions {
  tmux ls -F "#{session_name}" 2>/dev/null | cut -d: -f1
}
```

Here's what I did to glue them together.

```
function _tk() {
  compadd $(active_tmux_sesions)
}

compdef _tk tk
```

When I type `tk <tab>`, I get this error:

```
tk _tk:1: command not found: active_tmux_sesions
_tk:1: command not found: active_tmux_sesions
_tk:1: command not found: active_tmux_sesions
```

Comment: There's a typo in `active_tmux_sesions`. Probably should have spotted it before typing up such a long question...

Comment: @4ae1e1 Would you mind pointing out specificly what the typo is? I'm able to run the `active_tmux_sessions` function directly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `active_tmux_ses - missing s - ions`.